# Dapper value conversion

Tags: c#, .net-core, dapper

I am trying to add "UTC" conversion to all my Inserted/Retrieved dates with Dapper. Right now all dates are inserted as local dates. After some research I found a way to do it with retrieved values, by implementing `TypeHandler` as follows:

```
public class DateTimeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<DateTime>
{
    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, DateTime value)
    {
        parameter.Value = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }

    public override DateTime Parse(object value)
    {
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
}
```

The problem is with Insertion, it looks like `SetValue` is never called. What's the purpose of the method `SetValue` ? How to convert all DateTime values passed to SQL With dapper?

Comment: Do you add it to SqlMapper by `Dapper.SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler` ?

Comment: @zhimin of course.

Comment: this is a issue of dapper, please refer https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/303